# Matlab mex compiling with fftw3 not working

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, matlab, compiler-errors

I need to compile a c++ code as a mex file. It uses the library fftw3. For now I am just trying to run a simple fftw3 example code dowanloaded from

https://github.com/undees/fftw-example/blob/master/fftw_example.c

If I run it from the terminal it compiles the code:

```
gcc -Iusr/local/include/ -L/usr/local/lib -lfftw3 -pat_to_fftw_example.c
```

But if i run the same in matlab:

```
mex -Iusr/local/include/ -L/usr/local/lib -lfftw3 -pat_to_fftw_example.c
```

I get this error:

```
Error using mex

ld: warning: directory not found for option 'L/usr/local/opt/llvm/4.0.0_1' 
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

"_mexFunction", referenced from: -exported_symbol[s_list] command line option

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Anybody knows how to solve it?

Thanks

Comment: Fix your formatting, it's hard to read

Comment: I format it properly